# AJAX to PHP --> PHP not picking up the pass

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am still a noobie and still learning, but I can't understand why the data from an AJAX call is not being passed successfully into the PHP.

Where have I gone wrong here? I have literally spent hours on hours and I can't understand why the AJAX call hasn't posted this into the PHP. I believe there must be something wrong with either the data attribute from "  data: name+email" in the ajax call OR there is something wrong in the PHP side retrieving the data post from AJAX....

I am totally confused... 
Thanks for your help (and go easy on me!)

Thanks

```js
<?php

include_once 'db.php';

$fullname = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];


//this is the new stuff we are putting in
mysqli_select_db('table1');

if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
$checkdata = "SELECT signup_email_of_user FROM table1 WHERE signup_email_of_user = '$email'";
  $query = mysqli_query($conn, $checkdata);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
  {
    echo "err";
    exit();
      }

  else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (signup_name_of_user, signup_email_of_user) VALUES ('$fullname', '$email')";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    echo 'ok';
    die;



  }
}

 ?>
```

```html
    function submitform1(){
        var reg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
        var name = $('#signup_name_of_user').val();
        var email = $('#signup_email_of_user').val();
          if(name.trim() == '' ){
            alert('Please enter your name.');
            $('#signup_name_of_user').focus();
            return false;
        }else if(email.trim() == '' ){
            alert('Please enter your email.');
            $('#signup_email_of_user').focus();
            return false;
        }else if(email.trim() != '' && !reg.test(email)){
            alert('Please enter valid email.');
            $('#signup_email_of_user').focus();
            return false;
          }else{
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'test_signup.php',
                data: name+email,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('.btn-light').attr("disabled","disabled");
                    $('.sign-up').css('opacity', '.5');
                },
                success: function(msg){
                    if(msg == 'ok'){
                        $('#signup_name_of_user').val('');
                        $('#signup_email_of_user').val('');

                        $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:green;">Thanks for contacting us, we\'ll get back to you soon.</p>');
                    }else{
                        $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>');
                    }
            
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: data: name+email, theres the problem

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [mysqli](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) driver. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/6634591) has some good examples.

Comment: He hasn't even gotten to write that part yet, he's not getting data. I'm sure he'll fix it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed wrong:

```
data: name+email
```

Values are sent as key/value pairs.  All you're sending is a value without a key.  How would the server-side code know how to retrieve that value without a key?  Instead, consider something like this:

```
data: { 'name': name, 'email': email }
```

Then server-side you can retrieve the values by their keys:

```
$_POST['name']
```

or:

```
$_POST['email']
```

---

Note: The keys don't *need* to be the same name as the variables which hold the values.  They just seem to be reasonably applicable names in this case.  You could just as easily do this:

```
data: { 'first': name, 'another': email }
```

and retrieve the values with the updated keys:

```
$_POST['first']
```

---

As your form grows in complexity, there are a variety of ways to create an object in JavaScript to define the keys and values.  You could serialize an entire `<form>` in a single line of code, for example.  Or perhaps define more complex objects in JSON, serialized, and then de-serialize them server-side.  But starting with some simple key/value pairs would work just fine here.

Answer (score 0):

Your data seems to be malformed, try this:

```
var data = {};
data.name = $('#signup_name_of_user').val();
data.email = $('#signup_email_of_user').val();
```

and in the ajax: `data: data,`

According to jQuery documentation data attribute accepts following formats:
Type: `PlainObject` or `String` or `Array`

where the `PlainObject` is the one we need here:

```
var data = {'objectmember': 'objectvalue'};
```